# Python-3, BS4 removing ['...']

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am using python-3, bs4 and the following snippet

```
for result in results:
#   to find the src tag contents
#   .split('/')[-1:] removes all the text up to the final / and returns the name of the img file
    img_elem = result.a.img['src'].split('/')[-1:]
```

The text being returned is 
`img_elem = ['vwTiguan_001.jpg']`

I cannot find a method to print 
`img_elem = vwTiguan_001.jpg`
thus removing only the `['` and `']`

Thanks guys,
Tommy.

Comment: I suspect you don't want to slice here and just take the last element, eg: `img_elem = result.a.img['src'].split('/')[-1]` - note the lack of `:` there... You might also want to look at `str.rpartition` instead of `str.split`...

Comment: @Jon: Thanks Jon.  `str.rpartition` works a treat.  Would you have time to explain the difference between `.split`  and `.rpartition`.  As I understand`.rpartition` returns a 3-tuple and using `[-1]` returns the end tuple only.   Is there a memory and/or execution benefit in using `.rpartition`?

Answer (score 1):

Try python module called ntpath, instead of doing a split on the whole path to fetch the filename

```
>>> import ntpath
>>> ntpath.basename("/a/b/c.txt")
'c.txt'
```

Comment: @ apoorva: Thank you for your suggestion Apoorva.  I like my code to run as system neutral as possible as I work in both Linux and Windows environments.

Comment: @TommyGibbons ntpath should work for windows paths too. http://effbot.org/librarybook/ntpath.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replace method. Just replace the brackets with an empty string.

```
des = img_elem.replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Dropping the colon

The type of `result.a.img['src']` is `str`, a string. You're calling the [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method, which returns a list. That was those brackets are.

AFAIK in Python there's no method on `list` type for returning the last element. So you're stuck with direct access (using the `[i]` notation). As you've suspected, there's a trick to get the last element of a list without knowing how many of them are, and that's `list[-1]`, without the colon (`:`), as [Jon Clements suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62040915/python-3-bs4-removing#comment109729117_62040915). That leaves you with

```py
    img_elem = result.a.img['src'].split('/')[-1]
```

### Unpacking

Another way is to use unpacking/destructuring, like so

```py
elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
first_element, *after_first = elements           # first_element=1, after_first=[2,3,4,5]
*before_last, last_element = elements            # before_last=[1,2,3,4], last_element=5
first_element, *middle, last_element = elements
```

In these examples, `after_first`, `before_last`, and `middle` all hold a list (note the `*`), and their counter-parts have the item itself, without being wrapped in a list.

In your case, you'd have something like

```py
   *rest_of_the_path, img_elem = result.a.img['src'].split('/')
```

Comment: @A:  Thank you for your insight and I agree that Jon's suggestion is an excellent solution.

I had not seen your Unpacking solution before so thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who replied.  I will post the code that is working for me now.

```
for result in results:
img_elem = result.a.img['src'].rpartition('/')[-1]
```

`[-1]` removes the quotation marks ' ' from the resultant data